# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, post

Tengo este problema que me sale con una parte del código, a la hora de editar una fila de una base de datos, puedo agregar, eliminar pero no editar, por lo que pude ver no tiene nada que ver con el acceso a la base de datos, sino el enviar datos por post, estuve revisando los logs y me sale este error:

> [Tue Nov 08 12:03:10.182357 2022] [core:error] [pid 9532:tid 1860] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 127.0.0.1:55302] AH00127: Cannot map POST /equipamiento/%20 HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://intranet.lafedar.desa/equipamiento

Esta página es levantada por xampp, lo curioso es que cuando levanto el servidor con php artisan serve desde Visual Code Studio, el error desaparece y puedo editar con normalidad.

Aclaro que utilizo windows 10 y lo estoy corriendo localmente.

Esto es lo que me trae el boton para editar un equipo del inicio.blade.php

```
<!-- Boton para editar equipo -->
<a role="button"  class="fa-solid fa-pen default" href="#" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$equipamiento->id_equipamiento}}" data-ip="{{$equipamiento->ip}}" data-marca="{{$equipamiento->marca}}" data-modelo=" {{$equipamiento->modelo}}" data-tipo="{{$equipamiento->tipo}}" data-num_serie="{{$equipamiento->num_serie}}" data-procesador="{{$equipamiento->procesador}}" data-disco="{{$equipamiento->disco}}" data-memoria="{{$equipamiento->memoria}}" data-pulgadas="{{$equipamiento->pulgadas}}" data-toner="{{$equipamiento->toner}}" data-unidad_imagen="{{$equipamiento->unidad_imagen}}" data-obs="{{$equipamiento->obs}}" data-oc="{{$equipamiento->oc}}" data-subred="{{$equipamiento->subred}}" data-target="#editar_equipamiento" type="submit"></a>
```

Este es el script para editar el equipo que tambien forma parde el inicio.blade.php

```
$('#editar_equipamiento').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) 
{

var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
var id = button.data('id')
var ip = button.data('ip')
var marca = button.data('marca')
var modelo = button.data('modelo')
var tipo = button.data('tipo')
var subred = button.data('subred')
var num_serie = button.data('num_serie')
var procesador = button.data('procesador')
var disco = button.data('disco')
var memoria = button.data('memoria')
var pulgadas = button.data('pulgadas')
var toner = button.data('toner')
var unidad_imagen = button.data('unidad_imagen')
var obs = button.data('obs')
var oc = button.data('oc')
var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-body #id_e').val(id);
modal.find('.modal-body #ip').val(ip);
modal.find('.modal-body #marca').val(marca);
modal.find('.modal-body #modelo').val(modelo);
modal.find('.modal-body #num_serie').val(num_serie);
modal.find('.modal-body #procesador').val(procesador);
modal.find('.modal-body #disco').val(disco);
modal.find('.modal-body #memoria').val(memoria);
modal.find('.modal-body #pulgadas').val(pulgadas);
modal.find('.modal-body #toner').val(toner);
modal.find('.modal-body #unidad_imagen').val(unidad_imagen);
modal.find('.modal-body #obs').val(obs);
modal.find('.modal-body #oc').val(oc);
//desplegar select de tipo de equipo en editar equipamiento 
$.get('select_tipo_equipamiento',function(data)
{
  var html_select = '<option value="">Seleccione </option>'
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i ++)
  {
    if(data[i].id == tipo)
    {
      html_select += '<option value ="'+data[i].id+'"selected>'+data[i].equipamiento+'</option>';
    }
    else
    {
      html_select += '<option value ="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].equipamiento+'</option>';
    }
  }
  $('#tipo_equipamiento_editar').html(html_select);
});
//desplegar select de subred en editar equipamiento 
$.get('select_ips',function(data)
{
  var html_select = '<option value="">Seleccione </option>'
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i ++)
  {
    if(data[i].id == subred)
    {
      html_select += '<option value ="'+data[i].id+'"selected>'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';
    }
    else
    {
      html_select += '<option value ="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';
    }
  }
  $('#ips_editar').html(html_select);
});
});
```

Este es el edit.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editar_equipamiento" role="dialog" align="center">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">           
   <form action="{{route('equipamiento.update' , ' ')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">  
    {{ method_field('PUT')}} {{csrf_field()}}
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="title">Id equipamiento:</label>
          <input type="text" name="id_e" class="form-control" id="id_e" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('id_e')}}" min="6" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="title">Tipo de equipamiento:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="tipo_equipamiento"  id="tipo_equipamiento_editar" required></select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="title">Marca:</label>
          <input type="text" name="marca" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="marca" value="{{old('marca')}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label for="title">Modelo:</label>
          <input type="text" name="modelo" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="modelo" value="{{old('modelo')}}">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="title">Número de serie:</label>
          <input type="text" name="num_serie" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="num_serie" value="{{old('num_serie')}}"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="title">Disco (GB):</label>
          <input type="number" name="disco" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" id="disco" value="{{old('disco')}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="title">RAM (GB):</label>
          <input type="number" name="memoria" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="memoria" value="{{old('memoria')}}">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="title">Procesador:</label>
          <input type="text" name="procesador" class="form-control" id="procesador"  autocomplete="off" value="{{old('procesador')}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="title">Toner:</label>
          <input type="text" name="toner" class="form-control" id="toner" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('toner')}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="title">DR:</label>
          <input type="text" name="unidad_imagen" class="form-control" id="unidad_imagen" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('unidad_imagen')}}">
        </div>
        
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="title">Pulgadas:</label>
          <input type="number" name="pulgadas" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" id="pulgadas" value="{{old('pulgadas')}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label for="title">Subred:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="ips"  id="ips_editar"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="title">Dirección IP:</label>
          <input type="text" name="ip" class="form-control" id="ip" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('ip')}}">
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="title">Observación:</label>
          <input type="text" name="obs" class="form-control" id="obs" autocomplete="off"  value="{{old('obs')}}">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="title">Orden de compra:</label>
          <input type="text" name="oc" class="form-control" id="oc" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('oc')}}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Editar</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>                
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Y por ultimo el EquipamientoController.php

```
public function modal_editar_equipamiento (Request $request,$id)
{
    return DB::table('equipamientos')
    ->leftjoin('tipo_equipamiento','equipamientos.tipo','tipo_equipamiento.id')
    ->leftjoin('ips','equipamientos.subred','ips.id')
    ->where('equipamientos.id_e',$id)
    ->first();
}

//modificar equipamiento
public function update(Request $request)
{   
   $equipamiento = DB::table('equipamientos')
    ->where('equipamientos.id_e',$request['id_e'])
    ->update([
        'id_e' => $request['id_e'],
        'marca' => $request['marca'],
        'modelo' => $request['modelo'],
        'num_serie' => $request['num_serie'],
        'ip' => $request['ip'],
        'subred' => $request['ips'],
        'obs' => $request['obs'],
        'pulgadas' => $request['pulgadas'],
        'procesador' => $request['procesador'],
        'disco' => $request['disco'],
        'memoria' => $request['memoria'],
        'tipo' => $request['tipo_equipamiento'],
        'toner' => $request['toner'],
        'unidad_imagen' => $request['unidad_imagen'],
        'oc' => $request['oc']
    ]);      
    //mensaje de equipamiento modificado
    Session::flash('message','Equipamiento modificado con éxito');
    Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
    
    return redirect('equipamiento');
}
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que el problema lo tienes en la URL del post del form, pues has puesto esto: `{{route('equipamiento.update' , ' ')}}`  y segun el error, se está llevando ese espacio vacio y lo traduce a `%20` cuando se ejecuta el formulario

Comment: Cuando estas editando un registro en Laravel, la ruta debe contener como parámetro o bien el registro (model binding) o bien el id de ese registro. No podes pasar como parámetro un espacio en blanco, ya que eso sera un codigo inexistente en la tabla.

Comment: Que es lo que deberia hacer? porque asi me funciona en produccion y en desarrollo con php artisan serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al finar era la ruta en `edit.blade.php`, cambiando `{{route('equipamiento.update', ' ')}}` por `{{route('equipamiento.update', 'equipamiento')}}`